# Jenkins scriptler plugin keep running script on master

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have this pipeline:

```
    pipeline {
    agent { label "node-1" }

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                
                script {
                    env.RELEASE_SCOPE = input message: 'User input required', ok: 'Release!',
                            parameters: [
                                [
                                    $class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
                                    name: 'list',  
                                    choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
                                    script: [
                                        $class: 'org.biouno.unochoice.model.ScriptlerScript',
                                        scriptlerScriptId:'list_dirs.groovy',
                                        parameters: [
                                            [name:'node', value: "node-1"]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that the script keeps running on the `master` node and not on `node-1`
What I am doing wrong?